# Adjust batch file output to text file

Tags: batch-file

So I´ll explain it a bit here.

I need to create a CSV file but setting the file names one by one is a pain so I was thinking of creating a bat file.

So here's what I have figured out, or actually copied and applied.

In my batch file I got the following code :

```
dir /b > myFiles.txt
```

Nice and easy it gives me the following result in the text file:

```
59019694038.jpg
59019694038_1.jpg
59019694038_2.jpg
59019694038_3.jpg
59019694038_4.jpg
59019694045.jpg
59019694045_1.jpg
59019694045_2.jpg
59019694045_3.jpg
bat.bat
myFiles.txt
```

But to make things even easier to do I'd like to add a **`;`** after each file it finds.

So the result will be like this :

```
59019694038.jpg;
59019694038_1.jpg;
59019694038_2.jpg;
59019694038_3.jpg;
59019694038_4.jpg;
59019694045.jpg;
59019694045_1.jpg;
59019694045_2.jpg;
59019694045_3.jpg;
bat.bat;
myFiles.txt;
```

So my question was if anybody could explain me what I'm currently doing and how I could get this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your `DIR ...` with:

```
(FOR %%f IN (*.*) DO @ECHO %%f;)>myFiles.txt
```

That's a lot easier than parsing file and replacing each line.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! but I need it to be easily copy-able, so is there a way to remove the file location from the text file?

so I'm getting this result : Z:\Persoonlijke mappen\me>ECHO 59019694038.jpg; 
59019694038.jpg;

__________________

And I need it to be like this :

59019694038.jpg; 
59019694038.jpg;

Comment: Fixed. @ missing

Comment: now I do wonder if it is possible to get the sorted items in one line, I don't know how to explain this so I'll give an example.

right now I got the result I previously asked for but I would like to take this a step further. 
Each line contains one file but I would like to change that.

Instead of having to sort out things I would like to be able to easily copy paste per line,

so instead of 
this :
12836791.jpg;
12836791_2.jpg;
12836791_3.jpg;
12838445.jpg;

I would like to have a result per line like this :
12836791.jpg; 12836791_2.jpg; 12836791_3.jpg;
12838445.jpg;

Comment: this might make it a bit more clear : 
        ->    https://gyazo.com/26fbb75062459b304f04763cdc54e459

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the line breaks, you can adapt LS_DEV's command:

```
(FOR %%f IN (*.*) DO @ECHO|set /P=%%f;)>myFiles.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative answer which hopefully outputs them on a single line:

```bat
@(For %%A In (*) Do @Set/P "=%%A;"<Nul)>"..\myFiles.txt"
```

In this case I have sent the output to `myFiles.txt` in the parent of the current directory, just so that it isn't included in it's own results. You can optionally change that to an alternative location or have it included in it's own content if you wish.